# Asterisk In Front Of Name Of Function

Tags: c, pointers

I came across a function declaration that looks like this:

```c
void *functionName() {
  // ...
}
```

What does the asterisk in front of the function name do? I tried googling for an answer, but I don't know how to formulate the question so that I actually find what I'm searching for.

Comment: function is returning `void *` a void pointer

Comment: What does the asterisk do in a declaration like `int* x;` (which is syntactically identical to `int *x;`)? Why do you think your function declaration is any different?